# Why do I see open JDK 1.8 instead of Java 8?

Tags: java

When I check my Java version like this:

```
java -version
```

I see `openjdk version 1.8.0 runtime environment build ...`, but I thought I had *Java 8* installed.

Why does the version number show up as 1.8?

Comment: so why is not saying java 8 but java 1.8

Comment: java 8 === java  1.8

Comment: is this some convention, and if so what is this 1 in fron t of 8 for?

Comment: @leonardkraemer Good point. I took a closer look after posting that comment and noticed there was no explanation of the relationship between "JDK 8" and "Java version 1.8".

Answer (score 42):

From [Java Platform, Standard Edition 8 Names and Versions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk8-naming-2157130.html):

> In JDK 8 and JRE 8, the version strings are 1.8 and 1.8.0

Why? Because the developers of Java chose to name the versions like this. I can only assume the real reasons, but I think it is, because naming it Java 8 implies that it is new and much better than Java 7 but keeping the version bump from 1.7 to 1.8 indicates that it is still version 1.x and therefore still backwards compatible. In the end it is marketing.

See also [Why is Java version 1.X referred to as Java X?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175075/why-is-java-version-1-x-referred-to-as-java-x).

Comment: "Because the developers of Java chose to name the versions like this." Most likely the marketing department made this decision, not the developers.

Comment: I want to see the marketer that adjusts the string ;)

Comment: I don't understand how that contradicts my assertion. The person carrying out the task isn't necessarily the one who decided that task was the thing that needs done.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry if you misunderstood the funny remark. For Java you are probably right, but I like to keep the illusion for myself that I can pick my own version names :-)

Answer (score 14):

Before Java 9, Java version `X` was internally specified as `1.X` according to [these specs](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/versioning-naming.html).

Then came [JEP 223](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223) which proposed to change the version to just `X` starting with Java 9.

---

It should be noted that different tools may even use other conventions. For instance in Gradle there is `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9`, `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10` and they only switch to the new convention in `JavaVersion.VERSION_11` (see their [code comment](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/dada0824ca013eec7a637422a995d78610d07cb7/subprojects/base-services/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/JavaVersion.java#L113-L114)).

Comment: Well no offense to the devs/marketing teams. But this is a mess! Especially when someone new simply wants to install a compatible JRE version for some application to run!