# jdk 1.8 vs jdk 19 are they the same product?

Tags: java

I am not a java developer so I do not know much about different versions of Java

I have an application asking me to have jdk 1.8+ but when I google jdk download I get jdk 19

the difference is big from 1.8 to 19

are these same jdk but 19 is a newer version of it  or not?

Comment: But yes, jdk 19 is a newer version of the same product as jdk 1.8, so it should work.

Comment: Any version at least 1.8 will work for you. Java's guarantee is that anything compiled will run in a future version's environment

Comment: @Bohemian This is incorrect. Java makes no such promise. They merely promise that it is likely to work. Java9 in particular broke a ton of stuff relative to the usual java release cadence. In comparison to other ecosystems even the 1.8 to 9 breaks are minimal, though.

Comment: For a trivial example, `javax.Generated` was removed entirely, various XML parsers were removed, `Thread.stop(throwable)`'s functionality has been fully killed off, javafx was removed, reflective access to lots of things no longer works, and much, much more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Those are absolutely different versions.

`Java 1.8` is also known as `Java 8` (initially released in March 2014).

`Java 19` is a non-LTS version released in September 2022.

After Java 9, the release cadence changed to 6-month releases. That's why such differences in version numbers.

In general terms, newer versions should be back-compatible with older ones.

Comment: And unless you have specific reason, there's little need to touch non-LTS releases.  Your lucky numbers are 8, 11, 17.

Answer (score 0):

Those versions are different versions of Java. Jdk 1.8 is for Java 8 (as Jdk 1.7 is for Java 7) and Jdk 19 is for Java 19. Take look at those links bellow to understand the versions history:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642402/why-do-i-see-open-jdk-1-8-instead-of-java-8#:~:text=In%20JDK%208%20and%20JRE%208%2C%20the%20version,Java%20chose%20to%20name%20the%20versions%20like%20this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642402/why-do-i-see-open-jdk-1-8-instead-of-java-8#:%7E:text=In%20JDK%208%20and%20JRE%208%2C%20the%20version,Java%20chose%20to%20name%20the%20versions%20like%20this).